# Install dcm4chee on Centos

Tags: dicom

I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.na-mic.org/Wiki/index.php/CTSC%3aARRA%3adcm4chee_install) and when I executed `sudo cp /opt/dcm4chee-psql-2.14.7/bin/dcm4chee_init_redhat.sh /etc/init.d/dcm4chee` on server, it appeared the follow:

```
  15:25:36,602 WARN  [BasicMBeanRegistry] javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException: preRegister() failed: [ObjectName='dcm4chee.archive:service=WADOService', Class=org.dcm4chex.wado.mbean.WADOService (org.dcm4chex.wado.mbean.WADOService@234f79cb)]
    15:25:36,602 INFO  [WADOService] Registration is not done -> stop
    15:25:36,606 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/opt/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mysql/server/default/deploy/dcm4chee-wado-service.xml
    org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable: (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at sun.proxy.$Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:251)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Did the proposed solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am right now trying to install dcm4chee on CentOS and I experienced the same problem. When I was looking for a solution I saw your message here, as well as your message on the newsgroups with some hints about possible causes and solutions.

It would be interesting to point from here to the [newsgroups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dcm4che/LHEguwGwUgo) with answers and additional information, since that could help to other users having the same problem

In short: The problem is **WADO** service unable to start due to the **JAI Image IO** library not being properly installed.

You should download the [64 bit version](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/jai_imageio-1_1-lib-linux-amd64.tar.gz) of the library for Linux, extract the files and replace just the original (32 bit) ones from those that you downloaded.

```
$ cp clibwrapper_jiio.jar $DCM4CHEE_HOME/server/default/lib
$ cp jai_imageio.jar $DCM4CHEE_HOME/server/default/lib
$ cp libclib_jiio.so $DCM4CHEE_HOME/bin/native
```

Now, your DCM4CHEE installation should be able to run on your 64 bit Linux machine.

Comment: If using Java 8+, you will need in addition to above solution, to force DCM4CHEE to use a Java7. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jap1968 fix, please verify the Java version you are using typing `java -version` on console.

If you are using Java 8+, install a Java 7 SDK and configure DCM4CHEE to use it adding at line 106 of `$DCM4CHEE/bin/run.sh` the following line (modify it to match your Java 7 directory):

```
JAVA=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.7.0/bin/java
```